# Ruby on Rails Gems SQLite errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

When I create a Rails app I am getting some errors and I have no idea what they mean or how to fix them. Instead of explaining I am going to output what is happening, I think this might be the best approach to getting help with this:

```
rails_projects$ rails new first_app
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install

Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.0) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.0) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.0) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.0) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.1) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.0) 
Using arel (3.0.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.2.0) 
Using activeresource (3.2.0) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Installing coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Installing execjs (1.3.0) 
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.0) 
Installing coffee-rails (3.2.1) 
Installing jquery-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (3.2.0) 
Installing sass (3.1.12) 
Installing sass-rails (3.2.3) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.5) with native extensions 

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/j3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/j3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local



Gem files will remain installed in /home/j3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/j3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: My first guess is that I might need something like libsqlite3-dev package but I can't be for sure that's the case and installing blindly is always a stupid move. :)

Comment: I installed the libsqlite3-dev package. After that installing gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5, then creating a new app worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **gemfile** and **paste** the code below into the **import** list of the **gems**.

```
gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'
```